# Deploy Ruby on Rails project on EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, amazon-ec2

I have setup everything and i am able to connect to the server via ssh on a free tier

now my project is how can i upload the server files and database?

I see that there are some gems in rails such as **rubber** that deploy the files to a server but how can i also integrate git so i can commit changes as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

For uploading the files, check out [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/). Another popular tool is [Vlad the deployer](https://github.com/seattlerb/vlad).

Here's a simple `deploy.rb` for a rails3 app (assuming passenger) that only needs one server right now (replace all the  with actual values):

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require 'capistrano_colors'

set :application, "<APP_NAME>"
set :repository,  "git@github.com:<USER>/<PROJECT>.git"
set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_to, "/home/<DEPLOY_USER>/<APP_NAME>"
set :keep_releases, 3

set :scm, :git
set :user, "<DEPLOY_USER>"
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

default_run_options[:pty] = true
default_run_options[:shell] = '/bin/bash -l'

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

role :web, "<IP_OR_PUBLIC_DNS>"
role :app, "<IP_OR_PUBLIC_DNS>"

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"
```

**Note:** you should ssh-add the private keys for the deploy user as well as the key you use for github before running `cap deploy`. (e.g. `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_dsa`)

### Database

In terms of the database, you can run migrations as part of a deploy via `cap deploy:migrations`, or independently via `cap deploy:migrate`. Just be sure to list a server with role `:db`

```
role :db, "<IP_OR_PUBLIC_DNS>", :primary => true
```

(*Note:* this is the server that will be used to run the migrations, not the actual db. The db should be specified in your `database.yml`).

Setting up the database itself is beyond the scope of this answer, but you can either run a db directly on the instance, or take a look at Amazon's RDS, which is really simple to set up and more stable than a db running on a single instance.

Comment: You can also list the keys in via `ssh_options[:keys]`, but I haven't fully tested that, so didn't include it in the response.